# Difference between EditTextPreference versions in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I’ve been trying to build a custom [EditTextPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html). However, I need to obtain the string from the dialog in `EditTextPreference` and persist it inside a String Set in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

There are two versions of `EditTextPreference`: `android.preference.EditTextPreference` (**which includes the `persistStringSet()` method**) and `android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference` (**which does not include the functionality to persist data into a string set**).

However, the rest of the preference fragment compat code seems to be using v7 preferences.

Is there a way to build a **Custom EditTextPreference** using the v7 version that would allow me to persist a String into a String Set in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: I'm reading the documentation for `android.preference.EditTextPreference` and I don't see a `persistStringSet()` method. What am I missing? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html

Comment: [Preference.persistStringSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.html#persistStringSet(java.util.Set<java.lang.String>)) is available in the latest support lib beta.

Comment: Got it. So my first question is why you need to use a string _set_ when the dialog only presents a single editable text field?

Comment: I am trying to add the user input into a string set. Basically allowing the user to input multiple cities.

But just realized that I had to update my support library in my gradle build to 26.0.0-beta2. 

PersistStringSet was just added to that version which came out in June.